# Cant run method from another class in ES6 Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I run the method from another class? It doesnt seem to recognize it as a function when it clearly is. I mean a class is an object. All I did was accessing it and calling that function. So what did I do wrong?

```
class test {
  constructor() {
    fooBar.worker();
  }
}

class fooBar extends test{
    worker() {
    alert("Hello World");
  }
}

new test();
```

Comment: Looks like an anti-pattern.  Instantiate `fooBar` not `test` if you need it's functionality.

Comment: Isn't worker() a prototype method? It's not a method of fooBar itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `fooBar.worker()` needs to be a static method or referenced using `this`.

The way you are calling it, would require the `worker` function to be static.

Comment: I tried it with this. I should have mention it but I always got an error which is why I abandoned the idea:  missing : after property id. Static works fine!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure it says I can answer in 2 minutes. One little question though. Im sorry, I come from Java OO so many things are different. Accessing a variable from the super class wont work with this. right? Just extended my code a little: https://jsfiddle.net/zuqrp1hb/

Comment: @Asperger: what you ask about wouldn't work in Java either. Not to mention it looks like a code smell to access a child class method in a parent class. When it comes to inheritance, Javascript is not THAT far away from other languages. Sure, you have prototypes rather than classes but all principles of OOP are valid, including SOLID/GRASP and patterns.

Comment: @WiktorZychla for your information you with the template method pattern but we dont have abstract classes or anything here.

Comment: @Asperger: refactor to Strategy, i.e. use delegation rather than inheritance.